# How can I create SEO friendly URLs for an ecommerce website?

Tags: seo, url, ecommerce

Presently I am working on a website which has url like this

- For category page `mydomain.example/c/10/t-shirts`
- For product page `mydomain.example/p/1023/printed-black-stripped-t-shirt`

I thought that this is not SEO friendly and thinking to move to a different structure, but confused in how exactly it should be named. Find few samples below that I am thinking of, please tell me is this correct or something else should be done

- Category Page: `example.com/category-name/`
- Sub-Category Page: `example.com/category-name/sub-category-name/`
- Sub-Category Page: `example.com/sub-category-name/`
- Product Page: `example.com/category-name/sub-category-name/product-name`
- Product Page: `example.com/product-name`

Answer (score 1):

Your URL's are already search engine friendly as they are currently rewritten but they can be improved to remove the category/product ID's which is what you're thinking of doing.

The best way to display your URL's however really depends on the hierarchy, depth and subject of your website as well as a matter of preference.

If your customers would benefit from seeing category/sub-category in the URL's for your products, then this would be a wiser choice from a usability perspective otherwise site.com/product-name will usually suffice. You'll also need to consider whether your products will be assigned to multiple categories as well as you'd benefit from deciding upon a canonical URL for your products then also.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend `example.com/category/productname+unique-id`,
like `example.com/jeans/levis-501-original-fit-123456` 
It will be short and clear, no duplicates possible, not changing ever (permalink).

These sites might have some useful content for you:
http://www.practicalecommerce.com/articles/3898-SEO-Optimal-Ecommerce-URLs
http://blog.kissmetrics.com/seo-errors-ecommerce-websites/

Comment: Why productname+unique-id? I have seen this in another major ecommerce website. Shouldn't it be productname/unique-id as a random number being appended with name google might not give it that much weightage isn't it?

Comment: the permanent linking is a big advantage if people are talking about a product. As your site is behaving right now it has its unique ID in its url, the Product id, 1023 in your example. Its most-likely buildup in the order of CatID+ProdID, so always unique and re-traceable to a specific product

Comment: Ya that right. I was asking about should I separate unique-id with + or /

Comment: / implies it's a child, and + isn't really used in URL's. I prefer (and use) -

Comment: sorry, the + is not right, in url breakdown its translated as a space. a dash(.) is better, or even a dot (.)
You could consider another ending as well. A .php, .html or / would be nice (for [backward]compatibility with other clients)

Comment: Ok then which one should I use product-name-uniqueid or product-name/uniqueid . Does it make much difference?